# Xpath to select selected tag names

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to access an `xml` file using `xpath`.

The current code I have come up with for `xpath` is:

```
//*[local-name()='namespace']/*[local-name()='querySubject']/*[local-name()='queryItem']
[contains(., 'searchTerm')]/ancestor-or-self::*/*[local-name()='name']
```

While my `xml` is as below:

```
<project xmlns="https://afdsl/skdflsk/d">
    <name>AbcPos</name>
    <property name="included" type="hidden">true</property>
    <locales>
        <locale>en</locale>
        <locale>de</locale>
    </locales>
    <defaultLocale>en</defaultLocale>
    <namespace>
        <name locale="en">AbcPos</name>
        <name locale="de">AbcPos</name>
        <lastChanged>2014-03-05T18:47:30</lastChanged>
        <lastChangedBy>userx</lastChangedBy>
        <property name="included" type="hidden">true</property>
        <namespace>
            <name locale="en">Database Layer</name>
            <name locale="zw">Database Layer</name>
            <querySubject status="valid">
                <name locale="en">qskxyz</name>
                <name locale="zw">qskxyz</name>
                <queryItem>
                    <name locale="en">qixyz</name>
                    <name locale="zw">qixyz</name>
                    <hello>searchTerm</hello>
                </queryItem>
            </querySubject>
        </namespace>
    </namespace>
    <namespace>
        <name locale="en">Names</name>
        <lastChanged>2016-01-12T12:42:46</lastChanged>
        <namespace>
            <name locale="en">Database Layer</name>
            <name locale="zw">Database Layer</name>
            <querySubject status="valid">
                <name locale="en">qsxyz</name>
                <queryItem>
                    <name locale="en">myName</name>
                    <hello>...Hi there..</hello>
                </queryItem>
            </querySubject>
        </namespace>
    </namespace>
</project>
```

I have to fulfill the following goals:

> 1. Xpath should return only English name of the tags `<name locale="en">Database Layer</name>` and not the other language name like "zw".
> 2. Xpath should return only selected tag name and not all ancestors.
>      currently it returns all ancestor names in all language i.e. "en" or "zw" as given below

---

The **current result** is:

```
<name>AbcPos</name>
-----------------------
<name locale="en">AbcPos</name>
-----------------------
<name locale="de">AbcPos</name>
-----------------------
<name locale="en">Database Layer</name>
-----------------------
<name locale="zw">Database Layer</name>
-----------------------
<name locale="en">qskxyz</name>
-----------------------
<name locale="zw">qskxyz</name>
-----------------------
<name locale="en">qixyz</name>
-----------------------
<name locale="zw">qixyz</name>
```

This is **what I want** as a result:

```
<name>AbcPos</name>
-----------------------
<name locale="en">Database Layer</name>
-----------------------
<name locale="en">qskxyz</name>
-----------------------
<name locale="en">qixyz</name>
-----------------------
```

You can **test** this [`xpath` code](http://xpath.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php).

Comment: if you want to test all structure steps, use such xpath:  `//*[local-name()='namespace' and *[local-name()='querySubject' and *[local-name()='queryItem' and contains(., 'searchTerm')]]]//*[local-name()='name' and @locale="en"]`

Comment: Thank a lot I was referring w3schools.com that has nothing useful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
//namespace[./descendant::hello[contains(text(), 'searchTerm')] and not(./ancestor::namespace)]/descendant::name[@locale='en']
```

It's slightly the other way around your logic. First

```
//namespace[./descendant::hello[contains(text(), 'searchTerm')] and not(./ancestor::namespace)]
```

chooses the first most outer `namespace` element, and then

```
/descendant::name[@locale='en']
```

gets all `name` tags with `locale` property set to `'en'`

Also I would recommend using this flawless [tool](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html), because the one by the link you have provided doesn't work for me quite as expected.

Comment: updated xpath's first part for more flexibility using not(./ancestor::namespace) instead of ./descendant::namespace